# Version 5.9: Which components does "drush site-alias --local" look for in ~/aliases.drushrc.php?

Tags: drush

In version 5.9, "drush site-alias --local" returns what I consider to be non-local sites, because they each have a remote-host and a remote-user component set in  ~/aliases.drushrc.php.

I don't understand part of this excerpt from "drush help site-alias":

--local   Only display sites that are available on the local system (remote-site not set, and Drupal root exists).

What does "remote-site" refer to -- some other component in  ~/aliases.drushrc.php?

Thanks,

Glo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering is done in the [`_drush_sitealias_user_specified_list()`](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/commands!core!sitealias.drush.inc/function/_drush_sitealias_user_specified_list/5.x) function with

```
if ((array_key_exists('remote-site', $one_site)) || (!array_key_exists('root', $one_site)) || (!is_dir($one_site['root']))) {
  unset($site_list[$site_name]);
}
```

So it looks like the `remote-site` option is used. But [the documentation for the alias settings](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/5.x/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php) does mention a this option. So this looks like a bug.

Note: the same condition is still used in the latest version (see https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/commands/core/sitealias.drush.inc#L164).

Comment: Since the documentation for the alias settings does **not** mention the remote-site option, I suppose I now have an obligation to request that it be modified.

Comment: @GloriaRom You could also modify the docs youself and submit a pull request on https://github.com/drush-ops/drush

Comment: The doc does not need to be updated, the error is in _drush_sitealias_user_specified_list() as 'remote-site' is not used anywhere else in Drush's code.